# How to add and initialize byte[] field with Mono.Cecil

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

I want to add a field of type `byte[]` to the `<Module>` class and initialize it to an arbitrary array of bytes using Mono.Cecil.  The following doesn't work.

```
TypeDefinition moduleClass = ModuleDefinition
    .GetAllTypes()
    .Single(typedef => typedef.Name == "<Module>");

FieldDefinition myBytes = new FieldDefinition("myBytes"
    ,FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.HasFieldRVA
    ,ModuleDefinition.Import(typeof(byte[])));

myBytes.InitialValue = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

moduleClass.Fields.Add(myBytes);
```

Here is the result in ILSpy (using the "IL" view).

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
    // Fields
    .field private static uint8[] myBytes at I_00000000

} // end of class <Module>
```

When I try to execute the modified assembly, I get a TypeLoadException with the message "Type '`<Module>`' from assembly 'TestApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' has a field of an illegal type."

If I remove `FieldAttributes.HasFieldRVA`, I get no errors but the `at I_00000000` disappears, which I assume means the field won't be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

For initilaize a primitive value, like if you want to init just `byte` the `filed.InitialValue` works perfect. I don't know exactly why it doesn't work here. Maybe Jb Evain can tell.

Note that if you define s static field and set an initial value, what happening is that you set an RVA and then in a static constructor, the filed is initailize with the data that exist in this RVA toekn.

So to solve the problem I advice that you init the field in yourself in a static constructor, without the use of RVA. In my case I initilize an byte array of 2 bytes.

```
var staticConstructorAttributes = 
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Private|
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName |
    Mono.Cecil.MethodAttributes.Static;

MethodDefinition staticConstructor = new MethodDefinition(".cctor", staticConstructorAttributes, module.TypeSystem.Void);
type.Methods.Add(staticConstructor);
type.IsBeforeFieldInit = false;
var il = staticConstructor.Body.GetILProcessor();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2); // if your array size is bigger than 4 you need to emit Ldc_I4_S or Ldc_I4
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, module.TypesSystem.Byte); //create a new byte array
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, myBytesField); //store it in the myBytes static field
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, myBytesField); // load the field
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0); // index
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0); // value
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I1); // store the byte value in the given index
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, myBytesField);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a constructor (static) for the `<Module>` class and assign the value inside this. Whenever the class is called, the constructor will be initialized first providing you with the value. I'm personally not sure how to set an initial value but you can fiddle around with some CIL or simply use an importer to import the byte from another assembly to your own.

You can find an example of this in another question: [Inject Method with Mono.Cecil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461472/inject-method-with-mono-cecil)

Comment: Please, dont post answer if you are not sure about it. so others may find difficult in finding answers to the problem.