# Inject Method with Mono.Cecil

Tags: vb.net, methods, inject, mono.cecil

How can I inject a custom method into a .net assembly using mono.cecil, and then call it in the entrypoint?
I like to do this to implement security methods after the binary is built.

Answer (score 1):

To inject method you need to get the type you want to add it the method and then add a `MethoDefinition`.

```
var mainModule = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(assemblyPath);
var type = module.Types.Single(t => t.Name == "TypeYouWant");
var newMethodDef= new MethodDefinition("Name", MethodAttributes.Public, mainModule.TypeSystem.Void);
type.Methods.Add(newMethodDef);
```

To call this method form the entry point, you need to get the entry point `MethodDefinition` and the new injected `MethodReference` and add instruction in the entry point method to call the new injected method.

```
var newMethodRef = type.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "Name").Resolve();
var entryPoint= type.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "YourEntryPoint");
var firstInstruction = entryPoint.Body.Instructions.First();
var il = entryPoint.Body.GetILProcessor();
il.InsertBefore(firstInstruction, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Callvirt, newMethodRef));
mainModule.Write(assemblyPath);
```

Note: Yes I know its C# and not VB but I'm sure once you got the idea you can easily convert it to VB.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the `Module.Import()` function.

Example Class can be seen in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heTCisgYjhs

Credits to TheUnknownProgrammer's importer class.